# File location macro for python (Jupyter notebook)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am new to python/Jupyter notebook. Is there a way I can save the file location as a macro so that I don't need to copy and paste the same location each time I open a dataset from the same folder?

```
dat = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Box Sync/real_world_validation/Data/mydata.csv")
```

I tried the following code, but did not work:

```
data = "C:/Users/Box Sync/real_world_validation/Data"
dat = pd.read_csv("data/mydata.csv")
```

Comment: `dat = pd.read_csv(data + "/mydata.csv")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get access to the data in the same folder, I post the answer by @abhilb here:

```
path = "C:/Users/Box Sync/real_world_validation/Data"
data = pd.read_csv(path + "/mydata.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if your notebook will always be working in 1 directory you could change the current working directory altogether

```
import os
os.chdir(r"C:/Users/Box Sync/real_world_validation/Data")
dat = pd.read_csv("mydata.csv")
```